# Improving query execution time

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am working with spring data mongo, I have around 2000 documents stored(would probably reach 10000 in the upcoming 2-3 months), I would like to extract them all, however the query takes around ~2.5 seconds, which is pretty bad in my opinion, I am using MongoRepository default - findAll()

Tried to increase the cursor batchsize to 500,1000,2000 without any much improvement(best result was 2.13 seconds).
Currently I'm using a workaround - I store the documents in a different collection which used for cache, extracting this data takes around 0.25 seconds, but I would like to figure out how to fix the original query execution time.

Would like the answer will return in less then 1 sec, less is even better.

Comment: Is the problem reproducible on the local machine or over the network? Can you `explain()` the query?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact details i cannot confirm you a method.
But for data selection queries "Indexing" will help you.

Please Try Indexing the DB.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/

Comment: IMHO not a good piece of advice: Indexing helps to find documents matching criteria (by avoiding iterating over all documents). Here, the author explicitly states he wants all documents.

Comment: Yeah, indexing won't help on that case unfortunately, need somehow to improve mongo repository find all method